# AngularJS $http use data into controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS so if the question is not 'intelligent' for you, please don't rate it in negative. If someone ask a question, for he isn't stupid.

So..

I would like to use data from an ajax request, like this:

```
    encryptApp.factory('getData', function($http, $rootScope) {
    var getData = {};

    getData.tot_of = function() {
        return $http.get('/path/to').then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    }

    getData.get_info = function() {
        return $http.get('/path/to').then(function(result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    }



    return getData;

});
```

In controller I use this:

```
getData.get_info().then(function(get_info) {
        $scope.get_info = get_info;
    });
// HERE THE $scope.get_info is UNDEFINED
```

I'm new in AngularJS and I don't know why does this. So, is there a method that I can use the json data outside the " then function ".

Thanks and please don't rate this question negative. Sorry if my english is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.get` returns a promise.

By essence, a promise is as Javascript saying:
"Hey ! I let you make the request, but please, I don't want to wait for you, so when you finished, please execute the callback I'm just passing you, since now, I will forget you since I have more code to execute while you're doing your job".

In other words, a promise's callback isn't executed immediately, since the goal is to not block the Javascript "thread" (Javascript is like single-threaded).

So your current code is acting like this:

```
getData.get_info().then(function(get_info) {  //the function inside this "then" IS the callback
        $scope.get_info = get_info;
    });
// Hey !! The request might not finish ! So don't expect $scope to have the value you expect here !
```

So the simple example to illustrate would be to imagine that your ajax request takes 100ms to execute.

Within those 100ms, your next Javascript scope is very very very likely to be already reached, having `$scope.get_info` not initialized yet.
Without promise, your next code, outside of the callback, that should not depend of `$scope.get_info`, would have to wait 100ms to start, wasting time.

> So, is there a method that I can use the json data outside the " then
>   function ".

There is a way, using broadcasting/emit ($rootScope.$broadcast/$rootScope.$emit) to trigger a corresponding event, but it's often more "anti-KISS" for a simple case.
I advise you to put all your depending code in the promise callback.
To clean your code, merely call a private function that you define outside the callback.

Comment: Understand. Thanks for your patience! I'll use a private function. Your advice was helpful :)